# Fazer um método esperar o término do outro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

Bom dia pessoal,
Estou com a seguinte duvida, ao clicar em um botão o meu programa faz com se execute 2 métodos simultaneamente, método de enviar e-mail, e método de gerar o pdf, acontece que o método de enviar e-mail sempre termina antes, por exemplo:

```
anexos.Add(new MemoryStream(PDF));
```

Quando chega nesta parte dentro da função de enviar o e-mail, a variável "PDF" ainda não foi criada porque a função de gerar o PDF não terminou ainda, eu precisava de uma maneira de fazer com que de alguma maneira, a função de enviar e-mail espere o PDF ser gerado.Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Faz sentido executar os métodos simultaneamente se um precisa esperar o outro terminar?

Comment: Então, é que a estrutura esta um pouco bagunçada e essa foi a unica maneira de se consegui fazer rsrs

Comment: Vc está usando async await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O modo mais fácil aqui é utilizar o [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) que basicamente "avisa" que algo aconteceu.

```
public void ExecutaTasksAsync()
{
    SomeClass someObj = new SomeClass()
    AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false); 
    // Cria e adiciona o handler de eventos para o evento demarcando que foi terminado
    EventHandler eventHandler = delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        waitHandle.Set();  // Aviso que o evento terminou
    } 
    someObj.TaskCompleted += eventHandler;

    // Chama o seu outro método async
    someObj.PerformFirstTaskAsync();    
    // Espera até o evento ser sinalizado
    waitHandle.WaitOne();

    // A partir daqui, a task está completa, então só seguir o código normalmente....
}
```

Isso é só um código de exemplo, você vai ter que modificar para se adequar ao seu código....

PS:: A mensagem do @jbueno é correta, não faz sentido eles serem assíncronos se vc precisa um esperar o outro.

Comment: Usando async await não evitaria todo esse código?

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi é uma solução também, mas como não tinha nenhuma informação sobre o código, optei por uma solução genérica que funciona independente do contexto

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção também é usar o [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx). Assim, você garante que o o pdf sempre seja criado antes de enviar o email.

```
ClassePDF pdf = null;

Task.Run(() =>
{
   pdf = CreatePdf();
}).ContinueWith(task =>
{
   //Pode verificar aqui por exceções lançadas na task anterior
   SendEmail(pdf);
});
```